# How to display the products in a table format on the category page?

Tags: magento

I have page of two columns with left bar. On the left side I have listed the categories and when I click on a category, the products display in the right column.

But there I have two options for displaying the products on the category page, one is "Grid" and the other is "list". And I want to display the products on the category page in a table form which will be my own custom table. So that it have one header row and then each row contains one product.

How will I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such file as

```
(your template)/(your theme)/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

There you can edit your catalog template.

Comment: on that file you have both display, grid and list. so be careful when edit to make it available on both  cases.